# regex on routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I have routes like this

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      match 'recepcao/produto' => 'recepcoes#produto'
      match 'recepcao/nota'    => 'recepcoes#nota'
      match 'recepcao/venda'   => 'recepcoes#venda'
      match 'recepcao/cliente' => 'recepcoes#cliente'
      match 'recepcao/status' => 'recepcoes#status'
    end
  end
```

I guess I'll have more actions, and i don't want to keep adding `match`on my routes
is there a way to do something like

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      match 'recepcao/*' => 'recepcoes#*'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, put a placeholder like the default route:

```
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

No need for a regex. See the [Dynamic Segments portion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) of the Rails routing docs.

Comment: I completely forgot about `:action`. worked like a charm. thanks a lot

Comment: So what's the final solution? Why is there "#" before "match"? Where to put this placeholder?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Because the default `match` route is commented out; this line is copied directly from the default `routes.rb` file. I don't know what you mean by where to put it.