# Trying to simplify some parts of routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to simplify this somehow:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      get ":domain/test1" => "home#test1", constraints: { domain: /[0-z\.]+/ }, defaults: { format: :json }
      get ":domain/test2" => "home#test2", constraints: { domain: /[0-z\.]+/ }, defaults: { format: :json }
      get ":domain/test3" => "home#test3", constraints: { domain: /[0-z\.]+/ }, defaults: { format: :json }
      # ........... and so on
    end
  end
```

Is there any way?

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850381/regex-on-routes

Comment: What aspect are you trying to simplify? The repeated constraints/defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like to use some sort of `method` in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
def record id
   get ":domain/#{id}" => "home#test#{id}", constraints: { domain: /[0-z\.]+/ }, defaults: { format: :json }
end

namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
       x = 10
       x.times do |i|
           record i
       end
    end
end
```

Very bloated, memory wise, of course.

The killer is the `:domain` constraint. I was ready to just create a `resources :home` call, with some custom methodology inside - but you'll have to define the constraint manually each time you reference the route you require

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

For your problem, you have to use:

`get '/stories/:name', to: redirect('/posts/%{name}')`